# Can I re-enter the US with a valid I-94 but without my expired visa-bearing passport?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, passports, i-94

I've exited the US for a short (few days) trip to Canada. I've used my passport, but forgot to take my old passport — which has my (unexpired) US visa (tourist).

My current passport carries my most recent US entry stamp, and my I-94 is still valid.

Is there any chance they'll let me re-enter based on that? I know one can re-enter with an expired visa, but this case is different: the visa is unexpired, I just don't have it physically with me.

Comment: How will you be re-entering the US?  Via land, air, or some other means?

Comment: Air, YVR to LAX.

Comment: Can you have someone mail it to you?

Comment: @MichaelHampton - yes, but time is short and I'd rather avoid mailing such documents if possible

Comment: I think it is unlikely you will be allowed in without it. Especially if your admittance stamp is annotated "VIOPP" which tells them to look for the visa in your expired passport.

Comment: Why do you say your I-94 is still valid?  The airline should have reported your departure, which would have cancelled the I-94.  Did you check the database?

Comment: @phoog: You are allowed to use Automatic Revalidation to enter the US without a valid visa (if it is expired or you did Change of Status from a different visa) after a trip of less than 30 days to Canada or Mexico, as long as your existing I-94 is still valid. So that means the previous I-94 validity still matters. The question is whether he can use Automatic Revalidation.

Comment: @user102008 Yeah, I never understood that with respect to the electronic I-94.  With a paper form you can decide to give it to the airline or not, depending on when you next plan to enter the US.  Electronically, what?  The record is in some kind of state like "closed but eligible to be reopened within the next 30 days"?  Or are departures to Canada held open for 30 days just in case?

Comment: For the record, the I-94's "Admit Until Date" hasn't changed. It's still in June 2016 in my case. So either the airline hasn't reported it, or the I-94 form on the DHS web site doesn't mention it.

Comment: What happened in the end?

Comment: We managed to Fedex the old passport from Los Angeles to Vancouver just in time for my departure, so we didn't get to test any theories.

Comment: @phoog It's "closed but eligible to be reopened within the next 30 days" as you put it, when leaving for Canada, Mexico or (for persons in F-1/J-1 Status) the Caribbean

Answer (score 3):

You would have been able to enter without your old passport. Given that you spent less than 30 days in Canada (this would have been true for Mexico as well) your visa is re-validated upon entry (automatic revalidation).

Automatic revalidation does **not** require you to present a visa - it is the I-94 that is required. If you originally entered the US by air or sea, your valid passport is enough (the I-94 is electronic in this case), and if you originally entered the US by land, you present your passport and paper I-94 form (which should have been stapled into the passport).

Source: https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/auto_reva_3.pdf

Comment: The CFR says that validity of an expired visa may be automatically extended, which doesn't apply to the OP since his visa hasn't expired.

Comment: @Berwyn "The validity of an **expired or unexpired** nonimmigrant visa may be considered to be automatically extended to the date of readmission and the visa may be converted as necessary to that changed classification". Besides, the fact remains that it is not a requirement that the visa be presented

Comment: According to https://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/22CFR/HTML/22CFR/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-500/0-0-0-1810.html unexpired is only for changed visas

Comment: @Berwyn You're right, I see it now. However, if you can get in on the sole basis of an unexpired I-94 if your visa is expired, why should it be any different if your visa is still valid? None of the info suggests that specifically, and I don't see, logically, why that should be the case. Any thoughts?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I can just imagine showing the CFR to the CBP agent who asks to see the visa to check if it's expired. Then rejects you because you don't have it. Or suppose they want to see your visa to check whether the I-94 is valid? It seems a bit of a risk without it being confirmed by someone or written somewhere. Maybe I'm too conservative

Comment: @Berwyn "Or suppose they want to see your visa to check whether the I-94 is valid" The I-94 is either a separate document or tied to the passport. Never tied to the visa

Comment: Just checked my most recent I-94 and it lists visa type used for entry. Don't know at if that would be of interest to CBP or not. I did enter the US once stamped in as visa waiver when I didn't have an ESTA and was travelling on a visa. Not sure what would have happened if I exited and tried to reenter with automatic revalidation in that case...

Comment: @Berwyn Not visa type, admission class, i.e. Status. For example, a holder of a B-2 visa who changed to F-1 Status without having an F-1 visa would nonetheless have F-1 as the admission class on their I-94

Comment: Correction noted

Answer (score -4):

No, you will need to show your visa for entry into US. This visa can be on your old passport too. However, you need to show your visa.

Comment: Can you please add some more? Like a link to an official publication  and a quote from that or whether it is own experience.